# How can I do eqJoin with two or more fields in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I need to do a join operation in rethinkdb (eqJoin) but using two or more fields and not only 'gameId'

```
r.table('players').eqJoin('gameId', r.table('games')).run(conn, callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example of passing a function at https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/eq_join/.  You can make a function that returns an array of the two fields you want compared for equality.